# Is there a way to "inject" a Basic Authorization header using the NetworkExtension framework?

Tags: ios, authorization, networkextension

I want to be able to provide credentials for a HTTP endpoint with the following constraints in mind

1. No user interaction. The user shouldn't be prompted for a username/password. Credentials are to be managed by the app itself.
2. Outside of an app's process. e.g. any request to the domain "foo.com" must have an Authorization Header defined.
3. The device must not be supervised.

Is something like this possible with the [NetworkExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension) framework?

Comment: You might be able to do it with a proxy network extension, but to activate it on an app, that App must be managed which means that the device has to be supervised or managed by an MDM

Comment: @qnoid Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @Mrug Haven't come across anything yet.