# iOS keep showing "Proxy Authentication Required" dialog even after passing username and password using NetworkExtension

Tags: ios, proxy, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I am using `NETunnelProviderManager` for implementing VPN with HTTP/HTTPS proxy.

I have Basic Authentication from the Proxy server to authenticate with it, and I need to update password at regular time interval.

So to set credentials for Proxy Server I have implemented somethink like below:

```
self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration.proxySettings.HTTPSServer = [[NEProxyServer alloc] initWithAddress:proxyServer port:proxyPort];
self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration.proxySettings.HTTPSServer.authenticationRequired = YES;
self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration.proxySettings.HTTPSServer.username = proxyUser;
self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration.proxySettings.HTTPSServer.password = proxyPassword;
```

After setting this detail I am saving preferences, and on next launch, if I load preferences I can find the value which I set there. But, when I start VPN and start accessing anything via VPN(Proxy) Proxy it immediately shows dialog `Proxy Authentication Required`. Just to double check, if I check the log of `self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration` I can clearly see my password and username but still, It shows a dialog box for manual entry of user Credentials for Proxy.

[image: Proxy Authentication Required]

It would be really helpful if anyone can give me an idea on why my already configured proxy password and username is not considered if I set it programmatically in properties of `NEProxyServer`

Can anyone suggest something which can help me in updating the Credentials automatically in the background without asking a user to enter the Proxy credentials, something like delegate that we have in `NSURLSession`'s case?

Any response and help would be appreciable.